# Google adsense not able to display ads on my website

Tags: adsense

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-4182107412513886",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

This is the code I have added to my html page. I got this piece of code after i created ad unit with adsense.

However, it allocates the container, but no ads are displayed there. Also, I have no policy violations anywhere in my account.

Also, the ad unit I create gets vanished automatically after 6 or 7 days